# Listing the files in a directory and all subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any class in ruby for listing all the files in a directory and all the files in the subdirectory?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You might look at `Dir.glob`. You can pass it the `**/*` path which will give you everything in the folder and its subdirectories:

```
records = Dir.glob("path/to/your/root/directory/**/*")
# Will return everything - files and folders - from the root level of your root directory and all it's subfolders
# => ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "dir1", "dir1/file1.txt", ...]
```

Since you probably want a list of files, excluding folders, you can use:

```
records = Dir.glob("path/to/your/root/directory/**/*").reject { |f| File.directory?(f) }
```

Comment: If I want list everything in special directory not current directory , what can I do ?

Comment: `Dir.glob("/path/to/my/directory/**/*")`

Comment: is it returns file extension?

Comment: For future googlers, to get only _files_: Dir.glob("**/*").reject {|f| File.directory?(f)}